# Using jq, get value of a specific key which is inside a shell-defined JSON object within an array

Tags: json, linux, xcode, shell, jq

Given:

```
   [{
    "customer.name":"malinda",
    "customer.details":"test123"
    }]
```

Using jq, get the value of "customer.name".

My attempt:

```
echo $response | jq -r .[] | "customer.name"
```

Comment: I need to get "malinda"

Comment: [{
    "customer.name":"malinda",
    "customer.details":"test123"
   }] try this i have uploaded incorrect one

Comment: Side note, you should _always_ quote your jq expression, preferably using single quotes if your shell allows it. Without it, your attempt wouldn't have worked, only because the `| "customer.name"` part was interpreted as a shell command, and not part of your jq expression.

Comment: @MalindaPeiris - Please accept the grammatical and other corrections (e.g. to the JSON), otherwise you might find the Q downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jq:

```
echo '[{ "customer.name":"malinda", "customer.details":"test123" }]' | 
  jq '.[]."customer.name"'
```

or without double quotes:

```
echo '[{ "customer.name":"malinda", "customer.details":"test123" }]' |
  jq -r '.[]."customer.name"'
```

Since the dot `.` is neither alphanumeric nor an underscore, you need to quote the key name.

Comment: @MalindaPeiris `-r`  output raw strings, not JSON texts, as said in the help.